# Read RDS: object not found

Tags: r, file-upload, load

I used saveRDS and the file was successfully saved in the working directory. However, when I try to import it, I get the following error:

```
# save the data to disk
saveRDS(dat, "./dat.rds")

# real
dat<-readRDS("./dat.rds")

Error in readRDS("./dat.rds") : object 'dat' not found
```

Any ideas why? I checked the wd, but it's the same.
Also tried to use load, but again, a different error, see below:

```
> custom<-load("./dat.rds")
Error in load("./dat.rds") : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘dat.rds’ has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

Comment: Your first code block is a complete mystery, thoese two lines work just fine for me. The second code block looks like you're dealing with an older `.rds` file, or perhaps it is corrupted.

Comment: `./dat.rds` will be a hidden file on a unix system, are you on a unix system? What us you just save it as `dat.rds` or in any folder which isnt hidden?

Comment: what does the [tag:file-upload] have to do with this? are you trying to do this in a shiny app or something?

Comment: @jcken, it will not be hidden, are you thinking `.dat.rds`? (The leading `./` just means "current directory".)

Comment: @r2evans oh yeah my bad!

Comment: dat is a large data.frame. Anyway I tried to use readRDS from the files (on the RHS) and it worked like a charm. I guess the solution (in my case) is to paste the whole path (even though my wd is defined). Weird. Thanks for the answers anyway!

Comment: While I'm glad that you got it work, something else must be going on here: `saveRDS` happily works with no path (just a filename), relative paths (e.g., `./`, `../`, etc), or absolute paths (beginning with `/`). The size of the data should not be an issue (as long as the save location has sufficient disk space and, if network, stable connectivity).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use the whole path.

I guess that (even though the wd appropriately defined) this has do with the specifics of the working network I use.